# Slice a list of objects

Tags: python, slice

I have a class Card:

```
class Card:

    def __init__(self, rank, suit):
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = VALUES[self.rank]
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.rank} of {self.suit} with value of {self.value}'
```

and I'm creating a `list`:

```
 ls = [Card('Nine','Diamonds'),Card('Ten','Diamonds'),Card('Eight','Diamonds')]
```

When I print:

```
 print(ls[1:])
```

I get:

> [Card object at 0x000001884AAF3400, Card object at 0x000001884AB147B8]

as I've read I should implement:

```
def __getitem__:
```

but I'm not sure how.

Expected output is a list with string representation of card objects.

Comment: can you explain it more clearly! Try to post code what you are trying to do, what is expected and what is happening

Comment: You don't need to implement `__getitem__` to get a descriptive name for your instances when printing the list. It is sufficient to implement a humanly readable repr for your class: https://repl.it/repls/IncompatibleStingyVertex

Comment: While your answer is drawing a lot of tangential answers, I think you should update to describe your problem more clearly. Voting to close as unclear in the meantime.

Comment: `__getitem__` is what is called when slicing `Card`-objects. You use Python lists and want to slice these, not the cards themselves.
Your code actually works fine, but if you want a more legible representation of the items of the lists, you should implement `__repr__` to return `self.__str__()`. This is not exactly what `__repr__` is designed for, but should work for you.

Comment: Updated to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you have a list of Card objects and you slice it, you still get a (perhaps smaller) list of card objects. If you are at the interactive Python prompt, you have probably typed something like `my_list[1:7]` and got those [card object at...,] things. This is because when you type something at the prompt - or if you do `print (something)`, Python understands this as `print( repr(something) )`. If it were a string, it would just print it - but it isn't. Since you have defined a **str** method, you could do:

```
slice = cards[1:7]
slice_strings = [ str(card) for card in slice ]
print (slice_strings)
```

this will give you a nicer display, with each list item converted to a string by your `__str__()` method.

You might also define your own `__repr__()` method - the best way is to make it return something that looks like a `Card` object constructor, e.g.:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return f'Card({self.rank},{self.suit})'
```

then, doing `print (slice)` would give more satisfactory results.

Comment: Printing a sliced list was what I tried to do, but it doesn't return expected output, no item is converted to a string.
Altough, declaring __repr__ works. In one of the comments above it is stated that repr is not designed to do that. What would be a proper way then?

Comment: Using print() on anything that's not a string is not something you should do as part of your program, but is OK for testing. To make it work, use the second approach - define `__repr__` in your card class, so Python will know how you want it printed.